# Problem when calling a function in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$content = "... [gallery=174] ... ";
echo $c = preg_replace('/\[gallery=([0-9]+)\]/',gallery("$1"),$content);
function gallery($id)
{
   mysql_query("select * from `table` where `id` = '$id'");
}
```

but as `$id` it understand `$1`, instead of `174` in query.

What is the reason? And how can i fix it?

Thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible using `preg_replace`: `gallery()` will be executed *before* the string is searched, you can't specify the `$1` result in its parameters.

You are looking for [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** if you are trying to replace it, you need to use `preg_replace_callback()` instead, like so:

```
$c = preg_replace_callback('/\[gallery=([0-9]+)\]/', 'gallery', $m);

function gallery($m)
{
   $id = (int) $m[1];
   $result = mysql_query("select * from `table` where `id` = '$id'");

   // Fetch $result and return the appropriate gallery code here
}
```

---

**Old answer**

You should use `preg_match()` to find the match because you're not trying to replace it with an SQL query, simply obtaining the value from the string to use in the SQL query. Try this:

```
$m = array();
preg_match('/\[gallery=([0-9]+)\]/', $content, $m);
$id = (int) $m[1]; // The value of the backreference $1
gallery($id);
```

Also I believe your `gallery()` function should return `mysql_query()` so you can analyze the result set of the query:

```
function gallery($id)
{
   return mysql_query("select * from `table` where `id` = '$id'");
}
```

Comment: But i need to replace it. if i have a text in`$conten`t before and after `[gallery=174]`, i need to store them, just replcace the [...] with some content (returned from database)...